# Essential Self-adjointness of the Quantum Runge-Lenz Vector

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

On page 200 of "A Course in Mathematical Physics, v3: Quantum Mechanics of Atoms and Molecules",  Walter Thirring poses the problem of showing that (the components of) the quantum Runge-Lenz (QRL) vector is essentially self-adjoint on a certain domain.  He provides a solution of this problem, which consists entirely of the statement that the indicated domain contains the span of the Hermite functions, on which  the QRL vector is already self-adjoint, but he does not provide a proof that the QRL vector is essentially self-adjoint on the span of the Hermite functions, and I cannot come up with one.  Can someone provide such a proof or a reference?

To be specific, the QRL vector is formally given by
$$ \mathbf{F} = (1/2) [ \mathbf{P \times L - L \times p} ] + m\alpha \mathbf{x}/\vert\mathbf{x}\vert ,$$
where $\mathbf{L}$ is the angular momentum operator
$$\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{x \times p}$$
and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ are the position and momentum operators.  (In the Schrodinger representation, $\mathbf{x}$ is multiplication by (vector) $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ is $(-i/\hbar)$ times the gradient operator.)

Every proof strategy I have attempted has foundered on the fact that the QRL vector is a third degree polynomial in $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$. One observation is that one may take $\alpha = 0$, since the $\mathbf{x}/\vert\mathbf{x}\vert$ term is bounded, and so will not change any domain of essential self-adjointness. In that case, the QRL vector is homogeneous of second order in $\mathbf{p}$, so it will commute with complex conjugation and will therefore have at least one self-adjoint extension.

Comment: [Eigenfunctions of the Runge-Lenz vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89659/eigenfunctions-of-the-runge-lenz-vector/447118) seems to say it has explicit eigenfunctions. BTW, the page you cite is in this ["preview"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=gK_1CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It seems as though the references in that page concentrate on eigenfunctions in the negative subspace of the hydrogen hamiltonian.  If there are enough of them, that would suffice to show essential self-adjointness of **F** on that subspace, but I take Thirring to be asserting that it is essentially self-adjoint on some dense subspace of the full HIlbert space.  (The use of parabolic coordinates also seems very different from Thirring's approach.)